# Link HREF dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic, href

Having several links in my webpage with the same HREF value, this value will change on a daily basis, i don't want to change all values of links (easily 20).
My question is : is there a way to store the value in one variable in the HTML code and make all links take theirs HREFs from this value ?
I know it can be done in javascript so whats the correct script and do i have to put it in the onload event ? below the script i use to change all links with the variable;

```
<span style="display:none" id="dynamiclink" data-alink="http://www.google.com"></span>
<a href="#" id="link1">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" id="link2">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" id="link3">Link 3</a>

<script>
const spanlink = document.getElementById("dynamiclink");
const dynlink= spanlink.getAttribute("data-alink");
document.getElementById("link1").setAttribute("href",dynlink);
document.getElementById("link2").setAttribute("href",dynlink);
document.getElementById("link3").setAttribute("href",dynlink);
</script>
```

Edited, here is my code, so to be more clear my question was can i do this with HTML, i mean is there a way in HTML to link element attribute as HREF to a variable,

Thanks again guys.

Comment: There are no variables in HTML, you have to do it with JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar it is not a free coding service, everyone knows, and no one asked you to code something for anyone, I am a delphi programmer and i just started few months ago webdevelopment i am a beginner and  the only project i am on is personnal and when i am stuck i ask, i have done it with JS but i am asking if this can be done with HTML,Sorry for you if you didn't catch the meaning of community website .... Anyway i read the links you posted ... everything is ok i think

Comment: "what's the correct script?" How do we answer that without writing the code for you?

Comment: In your `load` event listener, loop through all the anchors and assign to `element.href`

Comment: You could also use a `click` event listener on all the anchors, which gets the target to link to from JavaScript.

Comment: @Barmar here is my edit and the exact question, and sorry if my answer was a lil bit rough, it is 2.30am and still need sleep

Comment: As I said above, there's no way to link them directly in HTML. Your JavaScript is basically how to do it.

Comment: You can simplify it by using `class="alink"` in the anchors, then looping over `document.getElementsByClassName("alink")`

Comment: @Barmar that's a great approach, can you post it as an answer ?

Comment: @Barmar because it is way better than iterate 20 + items in the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all the links the same class and use a loop to set them all.

```js
const spanlink = document.getElementById("dynamiclink");
const dynlink= spanlink.getAttribute("data-alink");
document.querySelector(".alink").forEach(link => link.href = dynlink);
```

```html
<span style="display:none" id="dynamiclink" data-alink="http://www.google.com"></span>
<a href="#" class="alink">Link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="alink">Link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="alink">Link 3</a>
```